# Git Extensions rollback last 2 commits

Tags: git, commit, rollback, git-extensions

How can I rollback my last 2 commits in git extension, the commits are not pushed yet.

Thus the first commit is a merge with a branch, the second commit is a regular commit.

I am fairly new to git extensions and I accidently made some mistakes in those commits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right-click the 3rd-last commit and select `Reset current branch to here`.

Comment: What happens to the merge if I do that? Does it just rollback?

Comment: It is a reset, not a revert, so it will be like if the two commits would never have been made, they just vanish. Think of a branch as a post-it note that is sticking to a commit. With a reset, you peel the post-it note off and stick it onto a completely different commit which then becomes the tip of the branch.

Comment: My local code will not revert right? It is like the commits never have happened correct?

Comment: Thus if I pull again afterwards, does it work regular, Do I also need to do this soft middle or hard

Comment: Whether you do it `soft`, `middle` or `hard` defines what happens to your local code. If you do it `hard`, your local code (your worktree) will also be reset to that commit. If you do it `soft`, only the branch pointer is moved, but your worktree and the index are untouched, thus your changes are still in the index (added for the next commit). Assuming that `middle` is the Git Extensions name for `mixed` (I don't use Git Extensions), `middle` will move the branch pointer and also reset the index to that commit, leaving the changes only left in your worktree.